# Use function in JXLS template

Tags: jxls

My template has some function such as TODAY(), CHOOSE(),... but when I use Jxls to write contents, these function not working, its display 0.

How to make these functions works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it, put formulas inside $[]

Answer (score 1):

To have an Excel function evaluated you can try the following

- Put it into $[]
- Use POI API to indicate that formulas should be evaluated as explained in [Formula Evaluation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html). In particular you can try using `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evalua‌​teAll();`
  or try to force formula recalculation with `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`

Comment: could you give me an example?